# Database on mobile apps

Tags: android, database, symbian

What is the best way to implement a db in a symbian/android apps ... I need to develop a mobile app that stores data in db

Answer (score 4):

On android, your application can use an **SQLite database**.

See the following pages, for more explanations :

- [Using Databases](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)
- [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a native Symbian application then check the below given link.

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Database_Example

And if you are writing an app for Symbian using J2ME then you can use [RMS](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with SQL, in Symbian rather than using the (rather old) Database Example above, you might consider the newer SQL interfaces which are easier to work with:

http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/GUID-E35887BB-7E58-438C-AA27-97B2CDE7E069/GUID-C9A1CC1E-2398-5887-8C64-7B8EE0B22022.html

Answer (score 0):

For Android, there's only one best way to go: SQLite.

If you're not storing much data there are alternatives, e.g. single file text based storage, user preferences stores, ... as appropriate.